# Dative plural adjective and noun endings: den neuen Büchern vs. den neuen Autos?

Tags: dative

I'm a bit confused. For dative plural, nouns end with n, the adjective ends in en, and the definite article is den.

So, for example: Der Junge lernt von DEN neuEN BücherN (the boy learns about the new books).

But, in the following example, the noun ends in s: Der Junge lernt von DEN neuEN AutoS (the boy learns about the new cars).

Why does das Auto end in S instead of N, as per the default rule? I'm assuming because das Auto ends with the "o" vowel, but I can't find any rules about this.

Comment: If you use the long form _Automobil_ it's consistent again: _Der Junge lernt von den neuen Automobilen_.

Comment: Even if you'll find a rule, each rule may have it's irregular exceptions.

Comment: Forget about rules. Learn using the language. - Or in milder words: rules are only sticks to help you  slowly walk; but you walk better without a stick. Or more concretely: don't learn rules about case endings - learn [= memorize = get used to] the endings for each word and use them. Nobody who uses a language fluently is aware of "rules" while speaking; one simply knows the proper form 'by heart'.

Comment: I get told and read this advice a lot, but I have trouble understanding how it can be applied to German, since getting the wrong ending or case can change the meaning of a sentence. I understand that it's useful to get a feel for a language and familiarizing yourself enough with it to the point where it just feels comfortable and more natural, but I still feel like you need some understanding of grammar when it comes to German. You're right about fluency as I don't think of these rules with English (it's my first lang), but I still took English classes all my life and learned rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Articles, adjectives and nouns have different declination tables. You have to learn them separate from each other. Nouns also have a different declination depending on their nominative singular ending and gender.

There are a lot of words with vowel endings that are shortcuts of other words in reality, e.g.

> der Pullover → der Pulli, die Pullis
>
> der Kriminalroman → der Krimi, die Krimis
>
> das Automobil → das Auto, die Autos
>
> die Fotografie → **das** Foto, die Fotos
>
> der Rolladen → **das** Rollo, die Rollos
>
> der Akkumulator → der Akku, die Akkus
>
> die Dokumentation → die Doku, die Dokus

(Please note the word sometimes even change the gender in the process.)

If those shortcuts end in -i, -o, -u, they follow the declination of words ending in -a, which are all loan words:

> die Kamera, die Kamera**s**

That's the same for shortcuts ending in -a:

> das Motorfahrrad → das/**die** Mofa, die Mofas.

For the -e ending, the normal declination of words ending in -e is used.

> das Pennal → **die** Penne, die Penne**n**

Shortcuts ending in -a and -e are very uncommon.